# Installing mvvm in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light

I am developing Universal Windows app. I am installing the nuget for MVVMLight in Visual Studio 2015 but the ViewModel folder and the other folders that were usually added when I used them in Visual Studio 2013 is not added to my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you updated to Update 1? I had the same issues before the update, I dealt with it manually

Comment: Yep, its really doesn't add the folders automatically... But you can always add them manually - if you know the structure . If you don't - open a working project as a reference.

Comment: When I tried to create a new project, I get the option to create MvvmLight (Win10Univ). When it created the project, I get the folders as well as the ViewModelLocator. The code worked fine there, but I was wondering if it is  a good way to do it.

Comment: Why not? When I need Mvvm in my project most of the time I use MvvmCross - but sometimes its can be an overkill. What kind of application are you building?